# Is there a non-allocating way to get the difference between two LocalDateTime points?

Tags: nodatime

I do appreciate why differences between two `LocalDateTime` instance are expressed as Periods and not Durations, but I could not find a reason why `Period` is a class and not a struct.

I am helping to port a codebase that did lots of this:

```
DateTime t1;
DateTime t2;
TimeSpan diff = t2-t1;


// After port, with a surprising allocation
LocalDateTime t1;
LocalDateTime t2;
Period diff = t2-t1;
```

It seems like a bit of a perf/GC pitfall, and I'm just curious why Period is a class and not a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for `Period` to be a class is that it would be huge - it has 6 `long` fields and 4 `int` fields. That would be 64 bytes - an awful lot to pass as a method argument etc. While some other structs in Noda Time are "pretty big" they're not *that* big.

But it's worth noting that the two pieces of code do radically different things. The Noda Time equivalent of `TimeSpan` isn't `Period`; it's `Duration`, which *is* a struct. If you don't need a calendrical calculation, you might want to consider converting your two `LocalDateTime` values to `Instant` values in UTC (or avoid using `LocalDateTime` to start with), and then take the difference between those two instants.

Internally, there are non-allocating ways of getting "the number of days" between dates, for example... we could *potentially* expose something like that publicly, but I think it would be worth doing benchmarking first to prove this is really important. (The GC is pretty good at collecting very-temporary objects. Sure, it's not free - but I think code would have to be doing very little *other* than this for it to become a major factor.)

Comment: For the specific use case I mentioned, making LocalDate.DaysSinceEpoch public rather than internal would be the minimal necessary change.  I can then just subtract two numbers and avoid Period overhead or conversion to Instants entirely

Comment: @DaveMoore: I would rather avoid doing that - I've been trying hard *not* to expose epoch-related functionality as far as possible. I'd rather create a change which is slightly bigger, but doesn't tie our hands later on. I've filed https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/1450 to keep track of this.

Comment: Thanks - I'll switch over to that thread as soon as I get my github credentials sorted out for access from work